# Compilation issue in calling function of .o file in .cpp

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a temp1.c file having a function

```
int add(int a, int b){ return (a+b); }
```

and temp1.h file

```
int add(int,int)
```

I have created .o file from it by compiling

g++ -o temp1.o -c temp1.cpp

Now I have to use add function in temp2.cpp placed in a different directory. I have done

```
#include "temp1.h"
int main(){
int x = add(5,2);
}
```

I have to compile temp2.cpp with temp1.o so that I can create a temp2.exe which can call function add. How to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 g++ temp2.cpp temp1.o -o temp2.exe
```

Comment: I have to create .o from temp2.cpp and then temp2.exe from it? Where will I use temp1.o?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
temp2: temp1.o temp2.o
     g++ temp1.o temp2.o -o temp

temp1.o: temp1.cpp
     g++ -c temp1.cpp -o temp1.o

temp2.o: temp2.cpp
     g++ -c your/path/to/temp2.cpp -o temp2.o
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I M SAARI OLD HABBITARS

Comment: It would be better to use `$(CXX)` instead. Then you can define the compiler in use at the start of the Makefile instead of effecting a dependency on gcc.

Comment: @moshbear the OP asked specifically for g++(in his question). But you're right if it was a production level makescript I would write more variables and better rules

Comment: Good point. I missed that part. Also, since the OS in use is Windows (due to temp2.exe), the executable target (and `-o` argument) should change from `temp2` to `temp2.exe`.

Comment: @moshbear afaik it defaults to .exe on (mingw and cygwin)